# Media queries not generated in node-sass after node and yarn upgrade

Tags: sass, media-queries, yarnpkg, node-sass

We have upgraded node from 6 to 10 recently. I have upgraded yarn too. I have updated node-sass to latest version. Now when I do yarn install and yarn dev, my project runs and web page opens automatically. But the issue is media queries are not generated at all.

we tried updating webpack. We tried using mini-css-extract-plugin.

Comment: You forgot to post your minimal code example that reproduces this particular problem.

Comment: I thought nothing to do with the code. Build process is fine and page opens without error. But page is broken because media queries not generated. Please tell me what code piece I need to share for this issue

Comment: Your question must be so detailed that someone else can reproduce the problem by following the instructions. In particular, the words "my project" are too vague.

Comment: See https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/ for advice on asking good questions.